# Finding truth values without a truth table

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm new to this type of course and has this been hurting my head... I've been working at my homework and there are two problems that I have no idea how to do. Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

a.) The boolean expression $(p\land q)\lor r)\implies(r\lor s)$ is $\color{red}{\text{false}}$. Find the truth values of $p$, $q$, $r$ and $s$ without a truth table.

b.) Using only the operators $\implies$ and $\neg$, Find the equivalent boolean function of: $p\Longleftrightarrow q$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: In order for the implication $\big((p\land q)\lor r\big)\to(r\lor s)$ to be false, the antecedent $(p\land q)\lor r$ must be true, and the consequent $r\lor s$ must be false. The only way for the disjunction $r\lor s$ to be false is for both $r$ and $s$ to be false. Now we know that $r$ is false and $(p\land q)\lor r$ is true; what does this tell you about the truth values of $p$ and $q$?

The second problem is a bit harder. An obvious starting point is that $p\leftrightarrow q$ is equivalent to $(p\to q)\land(q\to p)$. The problem, of course, being that we don’t have $\land$ available to us. This suggests that perhaps we should look for a way to express $r\land s$ using only $\to$ and $\neg$. Look at the truth tables of $r\land s$ and $r\to s$:

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
r&s&r\land s&r\to s\\ \hline
T&T&T&T\\
T&F&F&F\\
F&T&F&T\\
F&F&F&T
\end{array}$$

They don’t look much alike, but they do have one important thing in common: both have a $3$-$1$ split in truth values, though it goes in opposite direction. If we replace $r\to s$ with its negation, however, we get a $3$-$1$ split in the right direction:

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
r&s&r\land s&\neg(r\to s)\\ \hline
T&T&T&F\\
T&F&F&T\\
F&T&F&F\\
F&F&F&F
\end{array}$$

If we could just switch the truth values of $\neg(r\to s)$ in the top two rows without changing anything else, we’d be in business.

- What happens if we look at $\neg(r\to\neg s)$?

Comment: since, r is false, for (p∧q)∨r to be true (p∧q) needs to be true, so p and q is true. Am I right?

Comment: @jhh: You are indeed right.

Answer (score 0):

a) 
I think you've made a typo.
I've assumed that the correct expression is (p ^ q) V r) -> (r V s)

For the statement to be false, the antecedant (p ^ q) V r must be true but the consequent (r V s) false.  (for example, "if ducks exist, then I am a pineapple").

When is (p ^ q) V r) true?  When  p and q are both true, or when r is true, or both.

When is (r V s) false?  When neither r nor s is true.

So already we can see (from the second condition) that r and s are both false.  Looking at the first condition, that forces us to accept that both p and q are true.